# Use MySQL data to build JSON multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to build a multidimensional array in JSON using data from MySQL. I need my JSON to looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test name",
        "dates": {
            "Feb 26 2019": 2,
            "Feb 27 2019": 5,
            "Feb 28 2019": 8
        }
    },
        {
        "name": "test name 2",
        "dates": {
            "Feb 22 2019": 2,
            "Feb 24 2019": 5,
            "Feb 28 2019": 8
        }
    }
]
```

The dates are how many times the name appears in the MySQL table. For example, "test name" shows up 2 times with the date of "Feb 26 2019".

Here is my php:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT date, count(date) AS `count` FROM $table_name group by date" );
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $valid_date = date( 'M d Y', strtotime($row->date));
    $data[] = array('date' => $valid_date, 'count' => $row->count);
}


$query1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT cuname FROM $table_name ORDER BY cuname" );
foreach ($query1 as $row) {
    $names[] = array('name' => $row->cuname, 'date' => $data);
}

print json_encode($names);
```

Here is the JSON that is getting returned:

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"test name",
        "date":[  
            {  
                "date":"Feb 22 2019",
                "count":"9"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 23 2019",
                "count":"14"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 24 2019",
                "count":"9"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 25 2019",
                "count":"7"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 26 2019",
                "count":"1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"test name 2",
        "date":[  
            {  
                "date":"Feb 22 2019",
                "count":"9"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 23 2019",
                "count":"14"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 24 2019",
                "count":"9"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 25 2019",
                "count":"7"
            },
            {  
                "date":"Feb 26 2019",
                "count":"1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The issue is that all dates and the number of times the dates appear in the table are showing up for each "name". I only need the dates for how many times each name appears.

Comment: This is (or should be) nothing to do with MySQL - although there should be only one query. This is (or should be) just about how to manipulate arrays in PHP - specifically, transforming a 2-D array into a multidimensional one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but how does it have nothing to do with MySQL when the data is coming directly from MySQL?

Comment: Can you show your table structure and rows snapshot? Your first query gets you the count with dates, but it is no where correlating to what name under that result should belong.

Comment: Is ```$table_name``` the same in both queries? Why don't you get everything from MySQL in a single query?

Comment: Yes, $table_name is the same. If I can do a single query that would be great but I don't know what that query would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with a single query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
    `cuname` AS `name`, 
    `date`,
     count(`date`) as `datecount`
FROM 
    $table_name
GROUP BY 
    `name`, `date`
";


$query = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

$res = array();
$i = 0;
$name = null;
foreach ($query as $row) {
    if ($name!=$row->name && $name != null) {
        $i++;
    }
    $res[$i][$row->name] = $row->name;
    $res[$i]['dates'][$row->date] = $row->datecount;

    $name = $row->name;
}

//Verify the array structure:

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";

//Build JSON:
$json = json_encode($res);
```

Comment: This looks great but unfortunately it's not outputting any info. It's just showing an empty array. It's showing: Array ( ) null

Comment: Still kind of the same thing. The only thing being returned is Array ( )

Comment: Just made one final edit after your comment - the structure was a bit different, now it should match your requirements. Well, it works for me on my local DB. Have you tried to debug if it gets anything from your DB by ```print_r($row)``` while in the loop?

Comment: Works 100% for me, outputted both the correct array and JSON. Please check your DB output from the query.

Comment: OK, my bad, it was ```ORDER BY src.cuname``` instead of ```ORDER BY src.name```. Please, try now and make sure the MySQL is returning data, I might have mistyped something else from your specific fields.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a PHP error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Does it return an error or an empty result? Did you submit the query in the Mysql console or some Mysql client? It will help with debugging.

Comment: I believe it's something to do with using $row['name'] instead of the format of $row->name. I obviously could be wrong though.

Comment: This is coming from the ```$wpdb->...``` library you are using to make queries to the DB. Please, 1) make sure the query is working itself by submitting it into PHPmyadmin, navicat, or the mysql console. 2) If it's not working, report the sql error, id it's working, try using another php/mysql library or simply mysqli.

Comment: You are right. I edited the post. Give it a try now.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW I just realized you even don't need the subquery (I updated the post again). You'd need a subquery only if you need to order/group some things in a different way on two stages, which is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your dates and count as key: value

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $valid_date = date( 'M d Y', strtotime($row->date));
    $data[$valid_date] = $row->count;
}
```

Comment: That just reformat how the same data is showing up.